# C++ How can I assign a datatype to a binary sequence?

Tags: c++, arbitrary-precision, multiprecision

I have a binary sequence. This sequence represents an arbitrary precision integer but as far as the computer is concerned, it's just a binary sequence. I'm working in C++, with the multiprecision library. I only know how to assign *values* to the arbitrary precision datatype:

```
mp::cpp_int A = 51684861532215151;
```

How can I take a binary sequence and directly assign it to the datatype mp::cpp_int? I realize I can go through each bit and add 2^*bit* where ever I hit a *1*, but I'm trying to avoid doing this.

---

REPLY:

Galik: My compiler (visual studio 2013) isn't liking that for some reason.

```
mp::cpp_int A = 0b0010011;
```

It keeps putting the red squigly after the first 0.

Also yup, boost multiprecision.

Comment: How is the binary sequence stored?  (and is it stored little-endian or big-endian?)

Comment: Which "multiprecision library" are you using?  (Oh, and can you [edit] your question with the answers to these questions, rather than answering in the comments.)

Comment: It looks like it is [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: The fairly obvious improvement would be to interpret the binary sequence as a sequence of `uint64_t`. That's not simply 64 times more efficient, it also saves bitshifts. On an slightly related note, I assume no sign. You may need to figure out how that works for your binary sequence.

Comment: Did you try using a *binary literal* `mp::cpp_int A = 0b00110010111001010010010101010`?

Answer (score 0):

How to construct a particular type of big integer from a sequence of raw bits depends on that particular type, on the various constructors/methods that it offers for the purpose and/or what operator overloads are available.

The only generic mechanisms involve constructing a big integer with one word's worth of low-order bits (since such a constructor is almost universally available) and then using arithmetic to push the bits in, one bit at a time or one word's worth of bits at a time. This reduces the dependence on particulars of the given type to a minimum and it may work across a wide range of types completely unchanged, but it is rather cumbersome and not very efficient.

The particular type of big integer that is shown in your code splinter looks like `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`, and Olaf Dietsche has already provided a link to its [main documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html). Conversion to and from raw binary formats for this type is documented on the page [Importing and Exporting Data to and from cpp_int and cpp_bin_float](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html), including code examples like initialising a `cpp_int` from a `vector<byte>`.